# How can I parse data from one column in a table and put the result into another with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Detail] (
    [DetailId]       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Text]            NVARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    [Detail]          NVARCHAR (4000) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Detail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DetailId] ASC)
);
```

In the text column of the table I have data like this:

Row Example 1:

```
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<p>SSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius
</pre>
<p>Detail: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
```

Row Example 2:

```
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<p>SSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius
</pre>
<p><br />Detail: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
```

Can someone suggest to me how I can take the data from the `Text` column, parse out and remove everything matching:

```
<p><br />Detail: ....................</p>
```

or

```
<p>Detail: ...........  ....         </p>
```

and put the matched data minus the `<br />Detail:` or `Detail:` into the column named `Detail`

Checking for invalid XML:

```
DECLARE @id AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @text AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml AS xml
DECLARE @count AS INT = 0

DECLARE C1 CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR SELECT DetailId, Text FROM Detail

OPEN C1

FETCH NEXT FROM C1
INTO @id, @text

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    SET @xml = CONVERT(xml, @text)

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT @id;
    set @count = @count + 1;

    END CATCH; 
    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 
    INTO @id, @text
END 
PRINT @count;
CLOSE C1;
DEALLOCATE C1;
```

Comment: If any way possible, I would recommend doing this somewhere else than in the database. SQL isn't really meant for this kind of stuff. If you really have to do this, it probably would be possible search for the start and end tags with charindex and use stuff to remove anything in between.

Comment: Sorry, misread the thing, so you want to keep that part, but same principle anyhow, instead of stuff, select that part only using substring

Comment: Will your data always be valid xml (i.e. all opening tags have closing tabs or are self-closing)?  If so you could cast to XML and work with the data there.

Comment: if it is a one time task just throw in a few lines of your favourite language to handle this. you may be able to do that using pure sql but the effort is not worth the result. if it is a test/study project try with XML handling instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
--setup example data
declare @t table (txt nvarchar(max), detail nvarchar(max))

insert @t (txt) 
values ('<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<p>SSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius
</pre>
<p>Detail: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>')
,('<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<p>SSed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>
<pre>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius
</pre>
<p><br />Detail: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus  non numquam eius</p>')

--if single detail line
--update @t
--set detail = cast(txt as xml).value('(/p[lower-case(substring(./text()[1],1,7)) = ''detail:'']/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')

--if multiple detail lines:
--update @t
--set detail = cast(txt as xml).query('for $p in p[lower-case(substring(./text()[1],1,7)) = ''detail:''] return concat($p/text()[1],''.'')').value('.','nvarchar(max)')

--if you also want to remove the detail section from the original data:
declare @id int = -1
, @d nvarchar(max)
, @x xml

while exists(select top 1 1 from @t where id > @id)
begin

    select top 1 @id = id
    , @x = cast(txt as xml)
    from @t
    where id > @id
    order by id

    select @d = @x.query('for $p in p[lower-case(substring(./text()[1],1,7)) = ''detail:''] return concat($p/text()[1],''.'')').value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    set @x.modify('delete /p[lower-case(substring(./text()[1],1,7)) = ''detail:'']/text()')

    update @t
    set detail = @d
    ,txt = cast(@x as nvarchar(max))
    where id = @id

end

--if you don't have valid xml the below code may work:
update t
set txt = SUBSTRING(z.txt,1,z.c-1) + SUBSTRING(z.txt,z.c+z.d,LEN(z.txt))
,detail = SUBSTRING(z.txt,z.c,z.c+z.d)
from @t t
inner join
(
    select txt,c,PATINDEX('%</p>%',SUBSTRING(txt,c,len(txt)))-1 d
    from
    (
        select txt
        , case when a>b then a + 3 else b + 9 end c
        from
        (
            select txt
            , PATINDEX('%<p>Detail:%',txt) a
            , PATINDEX('%<p><br />Detail:%',txt) b
            from @t
        ) x
        where a>0 or b>0
    ) y
) z on z.txt = t.txt


--display output

select * 
from @t
```

Comment: JohnLBevan - I tried your code but it would seem I have one or more rows that contained malformed xml.  Here is the error that I am getting: XML parsing: line 1, character 88, well formed check: undeclared entity

Comment: Would it be possible to do this another way (just by a simple text match) without first converting to valid XML or perhaps with a cursor so I could catch the few records that might not be perfect XML.  Alternatively could you think of a few lines of code that would allow me to show the rows that are invalid XML so that I could fix the XML in those myself before doing the update.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do without using XML - by using the `patindex` function and substrings.  Not sure of an easy way to check for invalid xml; you could loop through each record in turn, try to cast to xml, then catch the error and update a flag?  Sadly my lunch break's over so can't spend more time on this one today; will revisit tomorrow if still unresolved...

Comment: JohnLBevan - Thanks very much for your help.  Yes please have a look at the thread tomorrow and if still open then I'd appreciate your help / advice. The data actually needs cleaning in about a weeks time so plenty of time.

Comment: JohnLBevan - I found a lot of invalid XML with some code I added to the question so you can see it. Is there a way you could modify your code so it would skip invalid XML.

Comment: @SamanthaJ You could update the try statement to record the `DetailId`s by adding a line after `SET @xml = CONVERT(xml, @text)`.  I've provided an alternate version which uses `patindex` which should work regardless of whether you have valid xml.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to solve this problem, I would connect to the database and use a simple xslt copy transform and write each field back to the database.  Xslt will allow you more flexibility in how you deal with the html, too.

Here's a complete example of pulling a field from a local sqlexpress database, transforming the field, and writing the field back.  Some assumptions / notes:

- You have a primary key to identify rows (e.g., "Id" below)
- I wrapped the xml string in `<node>...</node>` to give it beginning and end
  tags.

If the xml does not parse, then skip the field and make a note of it.

```
class Program
{
    private readonly List<User> _users = new List<User>();
    private readonly string _connStr = @"Server=localhost\sqlexpress;Database=myDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;";

    public void CleanData()
    {
        ReadData();
        TransformText();
        WriteData();
    }

    private void ReadData()
    {
        string sql = @"select * from [User]";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        _users.Add(new User
                        {
                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
                            Detail = reader["Detail"] as string,
                            DetailText = reader["DetailText"] as string
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private void WriteData()
    {
        string sql = @"update [user] set DetailText = @detailText where id = @id";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
        {
            SqlParameter textParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "detailText"};
            SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "id"};
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(textParam);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(idParam);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
                foreach (var user in _users)
                {
                    textParam.Value = user.DetailText;
                    idParam.Value = user.Id;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                cmd.Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void TransformText()
    {
        foreach (var user in _users)
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(string.Format("<node>{0}</node>", user.Detail));

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XslTransform myXslTransform;
                myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
                myXslTransform.Load(@"App_data\XslCopy.xslt");
                myXslTransform.Transform(xdoc, null, ms);
                ms.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    user.DetailText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.CleanData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message));
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string DetailText { get; set; }
}
```

**XslCopy.xslt:**

**Note:** "text" output type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```